# Python Object math

Tags: python, getter-setter

I have the file addr with the contents

```
Name,Phone,Email,Year_of_Birth
Elizi Moe,5208534566,emoe@ncsu.edu,1978
Ma Ta,4345667345,mta@yahoo.com,1988
Diana Cheng,5203456789,dcheng@asu.edu,1970
```

I am looking to extract the data and display it in so that it looks like

```
Please enter in the current year: 2018
Name           Phone          Email          Age
Elizi Moe      5208534566     emoe@ncsu.edu  40
Ma Ta          4345667345     mta@yahoo.com  40
Diana Cheng    5203456789     dcheng@asu.edu 40
```

But each age should be calculated properly based on their year of birth. I have hardcoded in the year 1978 as a test case, but I am having trouble getting my age to calculate dynamically.

Here is my code, MyClasses.py:

```
class Subscriber:
        inp = input("Please enter in the current year: ")
        def __init__(self, name="name", phone=5206675857, email="your@email.com", year=0):
                self.name= name
                self.phone= phone
                self.email= email
                self.year= year
        def getName(self):
                return self.name

        def getPhone(self):
                return self.phone

        def getEmail(self):
                return self.email

        def getAge(self):
                age = Subscriber().inp-1978
                return age

        def setYear(self, year):
                self.year = year
```

execute

```
from MyClasses import Subscriber
import csv, sys

def main():

        filename = sys.argv[1:]

        filein = open("addr.csv", 'r')
        data = csv.DictReader(filein)
        user = Subscriber()

        recordList = []
        for record in data:
                recordList.append(Subscriber(record["Name"],record["Phone"],record["Email"],record["Year_of_Birth"]))

        print("%-15s%-15s%-15s%-15s" %("Name","Phone","Email","Age"))

        for i in range(len(recordList)):
                print("%-15s%-15s%-15s%-15s" %(recordList[i].getName(),recordList[i].getPhone(),recordList[i].getEmail(),recordList[i].getAge()))


main()
```

I have attempted to change the line getAge() to:

```
def getAge(self):
                age = Subscriber().inp-self.year
                return age
```

which means I have to set the year value to an integer. But I am not sure where to put it. I have tried this.

```
recordList.append(Subscriber(record["Name"],record["Phone"],record["Email"],record["Year_of_Birth"]))
    user.setYear(int(record["Year_of_Birth"]))
```

But I keep getting error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: I would suggest you to use pandas.read_csv to create a dataframe from your file and then carry out remaining operations. You would have very less number of lines to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is quite self explanatory. You are performing `-` operator on string and int.

In your code, `age = Subscriber().inp-self.year` after using `user.setYear(int(record["Year_of_Birth"]))` the 2nd operand is int but you forgot about first one, i.e. `Subscriber().inp`.

A quick solution would be to do take input as `inp = int(input("Please enter in the current year: "))` or use `age = int(Subscriber().inp)-int(self.year)`

**P.S.** I tried `age = int(Subscriber().inp)-int(self.year)` approach with your code and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
input("Please enter in the current year: ")
```

takes input as `str`. Cast this to `int` and try again. Similarly cast all `str` to `int` wherever you need. Reply if it does't work. Also please post the code that we can run to test

Comment: I have tried to cast to int in the Subscriber class, but it did not work. This is what lead  me to try cast using users.setYear in  main. Perhaps I am not understanding